# Flex : Translate Embed Image into BitmapData?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

- I am looking for good, and hopefully for fast methood to turn an Embed Image into BitmapData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your embedded image raster or vector? Raster becomes `BitmapAsset`, just instantiate and get bitmapData from it. If vector movieclip, instantiate it, then render with `BitmapData.draw`.

Comment: BitmapAsset ... this is really helpful, didnt know about it. :) +1

Answer (score 4):

If you embedded the image you could use the reference to Bitmap.bitmapdata.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        [Embed(source="assets/image.png")]
        private var embeddedImage : Class;


        public function Main()
        {
            var image : Bitmap = new embeddedImage();
            //addChild(image);

            // reference
            var bitmapData : BitmapData = image.bitmapData.clone();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need another Bitmap with same picture on stage, no need to clone - just set bitmap2.bitmapData to first bitmapData (they can share it.)

Answer (score 1):

just like this.

```
 var imgBitmap:BitmapAsset = new EmbedImage();
 var bitmapData:BitmapData = imgBitmap.bitmapData;
```

(or)

```
var bmd1:BitmapData = new EmbedImage().bitmapData;
```